# Reverse Engineering with Hibernate Tools in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, eclipse, sql-server-2008, hibernate, hibernate-tools

I use Eclipse Indigo with plugin Hibernate Tools (JBoss by red hat) for database connection I use Microsoft SQL Server 2008 JDBC Driver.

When I try to use Reverse Engineering tool (hibernate code generation configuration tool) to generate class based on database table, instead of "string" type fields I get "Serializable" type fields.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

/**
* Customers generated by hbm2java
*/
public class Customers implements java.io.Serializable {

   private Serializable customerId;
   private Serializable companyName;
   private Serializable contactName;
   private Serializable contactTitle;
   private Serializable address;
   private Serializable city;
   private Serializable region;
   private Serializable postalCode;
   private Serializable country;
   private Serializable phone;
   private Serializable fax;

   public Customers() {
   }

   public Customers(Serializable customerId, Serializable companyName) {
      this.customerId = customerId;
      this.companyName = companyName;
   }

   public Customers(Serializable customerId, Serializable companyName,
         Serializable contactName, Serializable contactTitle,
         Serializable address, Serializable city, Serializable region,
         Serializable postalCode, Serializable country, Serializable phone,
         Serializable fax) {
      this.customerId = customerId;
      this.companyName = companyName;
      this.contactName = contactName;
      this.contactTitle = contactTitle;
      this.address = address;
      this.city = city;
      this.region = region;
      this.postalCode = postalCode;
      this.country = country;
      this.phone = phone;
      this.fax = fax;
   }

   public Serializable getCustomerId() {
      return this.customerId;
   }

   public void setCustomerId(Serializable customerId) {
      this.customerId = customerId;
   }

   public Serializable getCompanyName() {
      return this.companyName;
   }

   public void setCompanyName(Serializable companyName) {
      this.companyName = companyName;
   }

   public Serializable getContactName() {
      return this.contactName;
   }

   public void setContactName(Serializable contactName) {
      this.contactName = contactName;
   }

   public Serializable getContactTitle() {
      return this.contactTitle;
   }

   public void setContactTitle(Serializable contactTitle) {
      this.contactTitle = contactTitle;
   }

   public Serializable getAddress() {
      return this.address;
   }

   public void setAddress(Serializable address) {
      this.address = address;
   }

   public Serializable getCity() {
      return this.city;
   }

   public void setCity(Serializable city) {
      this.city = city;
   }

   public Serializable getRegion() {
      return this.region;
   }

   public void setRegion(Serializable region) {
      this.region = region;
   }

   public Serializable getPostalCode() {
      return this.postalCode;
   }

   public void setPostalCode(Serializable postalCode) {
      this.postalCode = postalCode;
   }

   public Serializable getCountry() {
      return this.country;
   }

   public void setCountry(Serializable country) {
      this.country = country;
   }

   public Serializable getPhone() {
      return this.phone;
   }

   public void setPhone(Serializable phone) {
      this.phone = phone;
   }

   public Serializable getFax() {
      return this.fax;
   }

   public void setFax(Serializable fax) {
      this.fax = fax;
   }

}
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. Someone might be able to help you if you pose a question.

Comment: I am not a java programmer, but perhaps you could edit your question to explain why it's not sufficient to just do a search and replace Serializable -> String once you have gotten this far?

Comment: Ofcourse I can replace, I just want to know why generator uses Serializable  type.

Comment: ok, well that's your question. It does seem like nobody who actually knows java has answered, so maybe try editing it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit "hibernate.reveng.xml"
And map the JDBC fields to the Hibernate Types like

```
<type-mapping>
    <sql-type jdbc-type="NUMERIC" precision='20' scale="0" hibernate-type="Long" />
</type-mapping>
```

Also to get more concrete answer just specify the Database Table Structure of Customer(s) Table.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

add into yours *hibernate.reveng.xml* following type-mapping element

```
**<type-mapping>
  <sql-type jdbc-type="NVARCHAR" hibernate-type="string"/>
  <sql-type jdbc-type="VARCHAR" hibernate-type="string"/>
</type-mapping>**
```