# Serializable vaiable types in java

Tags: java, serialization

I have a class marked Serializable i.e. this class implements Serializable interface. This class has some variables of type Serializable. I am unable to understand that why these variables are of Serializable type.I know about the Serializable Interface. Please make this concept clear. It will be a great help. My class is-

```
public class DestinationGroups  implements java.io.Serializable {


 private int id;
 private Serializable name;// why serializable here??
 private Serializable description;// why serializable here??
 private BigDecimal rating;
 private Set destinationses = new HashSet(0);
 private Set destinationGroupRatingses = new HashSet(0);

 public DestinationGroups() {
 }


 public DestinationGroups(int id) {
    this.id = id;
 }

 ..........other code..............
}
```

Comment: If you wrote the class and don't know why you defined the variables to be `Serializable` who should know it?

Comment: I didn't write the class. This is auto generated class by hibernate.

Comment: What is it auto-generated from? A database schema? How does it define the columns in question? I agree that one would expect something like `String` or `BigDecimal` instead.

Comment: As for the need to have serializable fields: if you want to serialize a class and its fields the fields must be serializable as well. Primitives are serializable by default while classes such as `BigDecimal` etc. implement `Serializable`.

Comment: @Thilo yes this class is generated from a my database table where name and description fields are of nvarchar(max) type.

Comment: What prior research have you done? If you "know" about the Serializiable interface; what prevented you from searching the internet?  Why do you ask us for explanations; if you could study the whole topic ... all by yourself? (stackoverlfow doesn't exist to **teach**, it exists to help with specific problems).

Comment: I am asking for this specific problem I searched the Internet and I only found the definition of Transient variables not Serializable variables. That's why I asked this question here.

Comment: @Jagermeister should I write all the search urls in my question?

Comment: Well, when I run google; one of the very first links is http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm ... which explains in great detail what Serialization is about ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@JordiCastilla's answer explains what `Serializable` is, but not why it appears here.

The real problem here is Hibernate's default mapping for `NVARCHAR`.  In recent versions (i.e. Hibernate 4.2 and later) `NVARCHAR` is mapped to `String`.  In older versions, Hibernate maps `NVARCHAR` to `Serializable`.

If you are generating your Java code using the Hibernate Code Generation Plugin, then the solution is to edit your plugin's "hibernate.reveng.xml" as described here:

- [How to change Serializable to String when use Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30072231/how-to-change-serializable-to-string-when-use-hibernate)
- [Reverse Engineering with Hibernate Tools in Eclipse Indigo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456061/reverse-engineering-with-hibernate-tools-in-eclipse-indigo)

On the other hand, if you are having problems with Hibernate mapping `NVARCHAR` incorrectly at runtime, then this Q&A might help:

- [Getting Hibernate and SQL Server to play nice with VARCHAR and NVARCHAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237280/getting-hibernate-and-sql-server-to-play-nice-with-varchar-and-nvarchar)

Comment: That's exactly I was looking for. Thank you @Stephen C

Answer (score 0):

**What is serialization?**
Serialization basically is the conversion of an object to `bytes`, that makes this object easily saved, shared or streamed.

**Why attributes in class must be serializable?**
That means, all components in a Serializable object MUST be serializables itselfs or you will be breaking Serializable contract.

Find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) further Serialization info.

Comment: The real question (at least for me) is why nvarchar(max) does not get turned into String.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to serialize a class all of it's properties has to be `Serializable`. With this usage you guarantee to make all properties `Serializable`. 
If somehow name is an object which isn't serializable you won't be able to serialize whole class.

Comment: You won't be able to compile the application actually.